# I want to reset previous data every midnight in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, reset

I'm making a habit record app. When I press 'complete', I want it to stay until midnight and reset right away to record new day. What I want is working this function automatically whether users open app or not. Is it possible to do that without additional plugin or packages in Flutter?

Comment: If you are using backend as Node js or any database you can just program your server to do that.

Comment: @KrishBhanushali Thanks for your comment. I'm using Sqflite, is it also able to be used to reset automatically?